# Is there a simple or "one-click" unlock for sprint iPhone 6 plus IOS 8.1.1?

Tags: unlock

How do I unlock iPhone 6 plus IOS 8.1.1 from sprint?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not.

You need to talk to Sprint for them to unlock it, since they locked it in first place.